# Overriding BindModel and BindProperty in CustomModelBinder, but BindProperty never hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom model binder with

```
public override object BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext)
```

that checks session for an object and creates it if it isn't there, then returns the object.

In that same model binder I have:

```
protected override void BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor) , and for some reason  this is NEVER hit on a postback.
```

BindModel() is always hit, but breakpoint on first line of BindProperty is never reached.
If i comment out the BindModel() override, the BindProperty() WILL be hit.
  Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you calling `base.BindModel(args)` in your overridden `BindModel()`?  If not, the `DefaultModelBinder` won't try to bind the properties and won't call `BindProperty`.